# Node JS - Decoding Outlook msg file (not unicode format) fails

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku

I have a Node JS Heroku service which read an email message and returns a base64 string to build a pdf. This is working properly for Outlook Unicode msg files but when the msg file format is not unicode, it prints something like this:

[image]

And this is an example of the same email message, exported like Unicode MSG file:

[image]

This are some blocks of code:

```
import express from 'express';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import pdf from 'html-pdf';
import pdf2base64 from 'pdf-to-base64';
import fs from 'fs';
import MsgReader from '@freiraum/msgreader';
import utf8 from 'utf8';

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit: '50mb', extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '50mb', extended: true}));
```

---

```
const msgFileBuffer = Buffer.from(pdfInfo.rawData, 'base64');
const testMsg = new MsgReader(msgFileBuffer)
const testMsgInfo = testMsg.getFileData()            
htmlData = createHTML(testMsgInfo);
console.log(testMsgInfo)

response = { error: false, code: 200, message: Buffer.from(htmlData).toString('base64') }
resp.send(response);
```

What can I do to avoid this problem?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer by myself, but I'll post it for people that have the same problem.

Change this import:

```
import MsgReader from '@freiraum/msgreader';
```

for this another one:

```
import MsgReader from '@kenjiuno/msgreader';
```

It seems that are something wrong with this library and sometimes fails with Not Unicode files. This feature has been fixed on the @kenjiuno/msgreader library.